# XCode getting stuck in build if using OrderedDictionary in swift

Tags: xcode, ordereddictionary

if use OrderedDictionary in swift xcode getting stuck in build. once will remove project running successfully.

i have using xcode 13.2
and swift 5
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y35YW.png)

i need to maintain OrderedDictionary

Comment: Did you check out the build log to see more exactly where it get stuck? Maybe try to clean the DerivedData folder.

Comment: ```The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions```
after some time it will showing above error

Comment: @JoakimDanielson

Comment: What do you want? You need to research that error and find a solution, it isn't unique so you should be able to find information about it. I certainly can't help you with so little information.